# Cannot read length of object returned from express (react)

Tags: reactjs, express

I am trying to make a page which pulls a bunch of data about users and then then displays (this part is fine). 
However I would like a condition within the fetch so that if there is nothing returned from the server a token or something can be set.

All I want is to have a condition that finds if the fetch statement actually contains any information (I am comfortable doing the rest)

Here is a code snippet describing what I am trying to do.

```
 // sets the questions from sql into state for questions
  getItems() {
    var user = window.localStorage.getItem("User");
    if (user) {
      fetch(`/profile-work-station-detailss/${user}`)
        .then(recordset => recordset.json())
        .then(results => {
          this.setState({ AccountDetails: results.recordset });
        });

        if(this.state.AccountDetails.DeskLocation.length <0){
         alert("yes")
        }
        else if(this.state.AccountDetails.DeskLocation.length  >0){
          alert("no")
        }
        else{
          alert("damm")
        }

      } else {
      alert("user not set");
    }
  }
```

As I am returning a json these individual parts for the request would be used like below (this has been done in other parts of this js file with success to render this information)

```
this.state.AccountDetails.DeskLocation
```

Any advice ?

EDIT 
when the code runs I only get the alert damm.
I am open to other methods to do this.

I have updated this so that it now runs in the render method however similar issue  is still present.

```
class ManageWorkstations extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { AccountDetails: [] };
  }

  // sets the questions form sql into state for questions
  getItems() {
    var user = window.localStorage.getItem("User");
    if (user) {
      fetch(`/profile-work-station-detailss/${user}`)
        .then(recordset => recordset.json())
        .then(results => {
          this.setState({ AccountDetails: results.recordset });
        });
      } else {
      alert("user not set");
    }
  }
  //when the component mounts make the sql questions the
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      AccountDetails: this.getItems()

    });console.log(this.state.AccountDetails)
  }

  render() {
    var self = this;
    return (
      <>
        <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          {" "}
          <u> Manage Workstations</u>
        </h3>
        {!this.state.AccountDetails  ? (
          <ul>
            <Link to="/profile">
              <button style={{ float: "left" }} className="btn btn-secondary">
                Account Details
              </button>
            </Link>
            <button
              style={{ float: "left" }}
              className="btn btn-secondary"
              disabled
            >
              Manage Workstations
            </button>

            <DisplayAddWorkstation />

            <br />
            <br />

            {this.state.AccountDetails &&
              this.state.AccountDetails.map(function(AccountDetails, index) {
                return (
                  <WorkStations AccountDetails={AccountDetails}></WorkStations>
                );
              })}
          </ul>
        ) : (
          <ul>

            <br />
            <br />
            <div className="jumbotron">
            <DisplayAddWorkstation />
              <button className="btn btn-secondary" style={{ float: "right" }}>
                X
              </button>
              <h3>Work Station</h3>

              <li>
                <div>Desk Location:</div> Null
              </li>

              <li>
                <div>Additional Information:</div>
                Null
              </li>

              <li>
                <div> Date Added:</div> Null
              </li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As setState is asynchronous, maybe you should test directly with the results object, eg: `if(results.recordset.DeskLocation.length <0)`

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of how promises are asynchronous and how the `.then()` principle works, as well as the fact that `setState()` is async, and you can't lof its values on the subsequent lines

Comment: Okay I have taken it out of here and put in my render method. Please see the question for update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the changes you have to make?

1. `bind(this)` to the method.
2. `fetch` is async operation so you are already updating the state so you don't need to update it in the `componentDidMount`. Just call the method to trigger it.
3. No need to use `setState` in `componentDidMount` and in the `.then()`'s `setState` use a callback to log it. For logging you can make use of `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

---

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = { AccountDetails: [] };
   this.getItems = this.getItems.bind(this); //<------1.
}
```

then:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.getItems();  //<----------call it here
}
// You can make use of "componentDidUpdate" to log the updated state.
```

and:

```
.then(results => {
   this.setState({ AccountDetails: results.recordset }, ()=>{
       console.log(this.state.AccountDetails); // <----check the log here.
       // You can move your conditions here
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi this is useful but how would I then use this in my if statemtn ?

Comment: You mean in the before edit where you have different conditions? if yes then you can move them in the callback as suggested.

Comment: I've tried that it does not work correctly. It dies not understand when the account details are there.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation for checking an object length is different from that of arrays. hence, the following link(s) might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/how-to-get-the-length-of-an-object-in-javascript.htm

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-length-of-a-javascript-object/